# AndroidのDataBindingでGenericsのワイルドカードを指定したい

Tags: android

AndroidでDataBinding使用時に以下のようにワイルドカードを指定したいのですが可能でしょうか。
以下の書き方だとビルドエラーが発生します。
何か解決する方法はないでしょうか。

```
    <data>
      <import type="java.util.List"/>
      <variable name="userList" type="List&lt;?>"/>
    </data>
```

Answer (score 2):

DataBinding ではXMLに記述をするため、 [HTMLエスケープ](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes)が必要です。そのため、

```
<data>
  <import type="java.util.List"/>
  <variable name="userList" type="List&lt;?&gt;"/>
</data>
```

と記述をする必要があります。

Comment: こちらを使用した場合もビルド自体が不可能でした。具体的には次のエラーが表示されます `Error:cannot find type argument for ? in List`　ワイルドカード自体が使用不可能なのかもしれません